# How to stream live audio from iOS device to Wowza media server?

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, flash-media-server, wowza

I'm trying to find out how i can use wowza media server(which i just installed) to receive a live audio stream from an iOS device(Xcode simulator) and play it on a web browser(safari) using http live streaming. i just need direction, guidance or a tutorial to start with this, or just the basic concept of how it works.

sorry for the newbie question, but i really really did try digging up the documentation, their is nothing about iOS http live streaming specifically, they concentrate more on Flash streaming(flv).

Thanks.

Comment: i use RTMP lib (rmptdump) it's hard way , works but not good
https://github.com/sakrist/RTMP-Test

,good works with adobe servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use Wowza's MPEG-TS capabilities

There are a couple of Google hits and topics on the Wowza forums.  This one looks fine for getting you started: [Using an MPEG Transport Stream (MPEG-TS) encoder with Wowza Pro (MPEG-TS)](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?1587-Using-an-MPEG-Transport-Stream-%28MPEG-TS%29-encoder-with-Wowza-Pro-%28MPEG-TS%29).

You can then just click a simple link in Safari on iOS devices and it should work fine.  The like will look something like:

```
http://myserver.com/appName/myStream/playlist.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

Wowza recently released an addon called "Gocoder". By using it you can encode your live streaming from wowza supported ios devices and broadcast it to any screen.

You can download the encoder from here
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wowza-gocoder/id640338185?ls=1&mt=8

Here is the step to configure the Gocoder addon with live application
http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?500